# Let $R$ be $R＝\Bbb{Z}[x]/(f)$, where $f∈\Bbb{Z}[x]$. For fixed rational prime $p$, Why $R/pR＝\Bbb{Z}[x]/(p,f)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be $R＝\Bbb{Z}[x]/(f)$, where $f∈\Bbb{Z}[x]$.

For fixed rational prime $p$, Why $R/pR＝\Bbb{Z}[x]/(p,f)$ ?

I may use certain isomorphism theorems, but I couldn't do it exactly.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you tried defining maps between these rings? I believe the third isomorphism theorem is relevant here, but you should also know how to do this explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to think about this is in terms of basis.

First some definitions to understand the structure we are working in.

Let $\bar{p}(x), \bar{q}(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle f \rangle$, then $\bar{p}(x) \sim \bar{q}(x) \iff p - q \in \langle f \rangle$.

Likewise take any element $\bar{a}(x), \bar{b}(x) \in R$, then $\bar{a}(x) \sim \bar{b}(x) \iff a - b \in pR$.

Elements of $\mathbb{Z}[x]\langle f \rangle$ will be of the form $s(x) + \langle f \rangle$, and for $R / pR$, they will be $\bar{g}(x) + pR = (s(x) + \langle f \rangle) + pR$.

Lets define our isomorphism
$$\phi : R / pR \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}[x] / \langle p, f \rangle$$
$$\phi((a + \langle f \rangle) + pR) = a + \langle p, f \rangle$$

Proving injectivity, $\phi(a + \langle f \rangle + pR) = \phi(b + \langle f \rangle + pR) \implies a - b \in \langle p, f \rangle$. Which we can see means that $a, b$ represent the same coset in $R/pR$. Likewise the surjective map back is obvious.